# ACF Field on Elementor Post Skin, one widget works, the others don't

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

im trying to displaying a field on a post widget on an elemenetor post skin.

On one widget works, but when adding the post widget somewhere else, it doesn't show $event_date

Here is what I wrote out in my code at skins-cards.php :

```
public function render_badge() {
    
$value = get_field( 'event_date_field', false );

$event_date_field = $this->get_instance_value( 'event_date_field' );
if ( ! empty( $event_date_field ) && function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
    $event_date = get_field( $event_date_field );
    if ( ! empty( $event_date ) ) {
        ?>
        <div class="elementor-post__badge" style="z-index: 9999;">
            <?php echo esc_html( $event_date ); ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php
        // Output the event_date value to the browser console
        echo '<script>console.log("' . $value . '");</script>';
    }
}
}
```

In the code snippet above, i found that $value is null or empty. Currently when viewing the rendered element, its outputting the badge twice (overlapping eachother).

I'm not that good with PHP, but I assume there is something wrong with getting the instance value of the ACF field when reusing the widget somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
          **Here is the updated code please try this**


          public function render_badge() {
        $event_date_field = $this->get_instance_value( 'event_date_field' );
       if ( ! empty( $event_date_field ) && function_exists( 'get_field' ) ) {
      $event_date = get_field( $event_date_field );
             if ( ! empty( $event_date ) ) {
        // Assign the field value to $value
        $value = $event_date;

        ?>
        <div class="elementor-post__badge" style="z-index: 9999;">
            <?php echo esc_html( $event_date ); ?>
        </div>
        
        <?php
        // Output the event_date value to the browser console
        echo '<script>console.log("' . $value . '");</script>';
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: I tried this, but i see that you moved the $value below so that the variable is populated after the get_field function. 

This works to populate the console.log, but doesn't solve the other problem of reusing the widget somewhere else

Comment: $post_id = get_the_ID();
$event_date_field = get_field( 'event_date_field', $post_id );
You should pass the ID of the post for fetch the ACF data.